# Wrap innerHTML in div

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a JS function that updates descriptions of products when variables are changed. Here is where the element is updated.

```js
    Product.Config.prototype.updateProductShortDescription = function(productId) {
var shortDescription = this.config.shortDescription;
if (productId && this.config.childProducts[productId].shortDescription) {
    shortDescription = this.config.childProducts[productId].shortDescription;
}
$$('#product_addtocart_form div.short-description').each(function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = shortDescription;
});
};
```

Works great but would like to wrap the output in a div. Does anyone know a way or wrapping innerHTML in a tag before when updating it?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method?

Comment: please add all your relevant code for your question so we can help you better: html, js ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML` if you're just setting text. It is incredibly insecure and will happily execute scripts and contact any server that the text you're using can instruct the browser to do by simply including some malicious HTML code.

Use the `.textContent` property instead.

But better yet, since it looks like you're using jQuery anyway, just use jQuery's built-in way to construct elements as needed:

```
let div = $(`<div></div>`).text(description);
$(`.my-element`).append(div);
```

And if you already have elements:

```
let update = $(`<div></div>`).text(description);
$(`#your.query-selector goes:here()`).empty().append(update);
```

(because jQuery lets you chain calls in a way that make them apply to every element in a selection, this will set that div-wrapped description as content for every element in the query result)

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer, and was wondering whether the insecurity of `innerHTML` also holds true in the case of static websites that don't allow for user interaction via (direct+unsanitized) text-input. if `shortDescription` is not writable via user input, but, let's say, requires backend access in order to be modified, then this shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: you raise an excellent point, and I've updated the answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `$$` function is from, but there is my proposal in vanilla JS:

```js
const descriptionText = "my short description";
const descriptionElements = document.querySelectorAll('#product_addtocart_form div.short-description');

Array.from(descriptionElements).forEach(function(el) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('customDiv');
  newDiv.textContent = descriptionText;
  el.appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted silver;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_addtocart_form">
  <div class="short-description">1</div>
  <div class="short-description">2</div>
  <div class="short-description">3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

After reading your first comment, in your code you just have to replace:

```js
  el.innerHTML = shortDescription;
```

by:

```js
  const descWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  descWrapper.innerHTML = shortDescription;
  el.appendChild(descWrapper);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted the full function. I keep trying to put it in backticks but it doesn't seem to let me! I've edited my OP to show the full function.

Comment: Thank you for that. How can I assign a class to the div? I'm assuming this put the shortDescription inside a div?

Comment: `descWrapper.classList.add('classToAdd');` or `descWrapper.className = 'classToAdd';`. You may find more detail about [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) & [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) on MDN.